# How do I plot a cross correlation matrix for timeseries?

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have a timeseries representation of my data as follows (without the row and column) annotations:

```
      L1 L2 L3 L4
t=1    0  1  1  0
t=2    0  1  1  1
t=3    1  0  1  1
t=4    0  1  1  0
```

I am reading this into R as:

```
timeseries = read.table("./test", header=F)
```

I am plotting timeseries for L1 using

```
ts.plot(timeseries$V1)
```

and plotting the cross-correlation function as:

```
ccf(timeseries$V1, timeseries$V2)
```

Now, can someone please tell me how do I plot a cross correlation matrix that shows the output of this function for L1-L4? Basically, something like this (in my case, a 4x4 matrix of plots):

[image]

Comment: should this be sent to cross validate?

Comment: Hmm.. may I ask why? This is a question related to plotting in `R` which has its own language.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to plot each `ccf` of each pair of columns on a single plot?

Comment: @joran: Yes! Exactly. I updated my question to show an example.

Comment: Ok, I gave a very basic way to do this. But I'd be patient and wait for some more eyeballs, cause it's quite possible that there's a function buried in one of the time series packages (`zoo`, `xts`) that does something similar in a prettier fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be another trivial way of doing it!

```
timeseries = read.table("./test", header=F)
acf(timeseries)
```

gives me a matrix of correlation plots. Of course, there are other options that can be passed to `acf` if a covariance is needed.

Answer (score 2):

A trivial way of doing this is to simply create a matrix of plots on your plotting device and place each `ccf` plot in one by one:

```
M <- matrix(sample(0:1,40,replace = TRUE),nrow = 10)

par(mfrow= c(4,4))
for (i in 1:4){
    for (j in 1:4){
        ccf(M[,i],M[,j])
    }
}
```

But if you wait around a bit, someone who knows the time series packages more intimately may swing by with a function that does this a bit more nicely.

Comment: +1 Great! Thank you. I'll probably wait for half-a-day. If nothing else comes by, I'll accept this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this where `M` is as in joran's post:

```
pnl <- function(x, y = x) { par(new = TRUE); ccf(x, y) }
pairs(as.data.frame(M), upper.panel = pnl, diag.panel = pnl, cex.labels = 1)
```